# Issues with Clipping Shape of Sentinel-2 NDVI Image in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, shapefile, clip, ndvi, satellite

I'm working on an agricultural analytics application where I need to generate NDVI images from Sentinel-2 data for user-defined polygon areas. The backend is implemented in Python using Flask and the Google Earth Engine (GEE) Python API.

I've encountered a problem where the NDVI images produced do not match the exact shape of the polygons drawn by the users on the frontend. Instead of getting an NDVI image clipped to the irregular polygon shape, I receive an image that is rectangular and extends beyond the bounds of the specified polygon.

Here is the Python code snippet used for generating the NDVI image:

```
import ee

def calculate_ndvi(coordinates):
    """Calculate NDVI using the specified polygon coordinates and Sentinel-2 data, then clip the image to these coordinates."""
    try:
        aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coordinates)
        collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')\
                        .filterDate('2024-03-08', '2024-03-09')\
                        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))\
                        .filterBounds(aoi)\
                        .median()
        
        ndvi = collection.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
        clipped_ndvi = ndvi.clip(aoi)

        url = clipped_ndvi.getThumbURL({
            'min': 0,
            'max': 1,
            'dimensions': 512,
            'palette': ['blue', 'white', 'green']
        })
        return url
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error in calculate_ndvi: {e}")
```

Here is the image that I drew
[image]

and this is what I got
[image]

What might be causing the discrepancy between the expected polygon-shaped NDVI image and the rectangular result? How can I ensure that the resulting NDVI image is clipped exactly to the specified polygon boundaries?

I need the NDVI images returned by the Google Earth Engine Python API to exactly match the shape of the polygons drawn by user